# Should I need to cure the curve for the model?

Tags: deep-learning, training, multiclass-classification, epochs

I have several classification models that used for image classification. The epochs is set to 100 for both. Model A gave me accuracy 99.7 and stopped at epoch 100 but Model B gave me 99.93 but take much time than Model A and the epochs exceeds the 100 until 150 epochs the code is training.

Should I need to stop training at 100 for the both model for fair comparing or make each one running until the accuracy improve.
also the curve for the model A is
[image]

and the curve for the model B is
[image]

Should I need to cure the curve for the model B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the criteria you want to take into account when comparing your models. If your goal is to examine how fast a model is in training, you can stop here, but I guess it's not your objective.

To compare the accuracy, you should juxtapose models fairly. Currently, the range of y-axis labels is so different that we can't conclude whether it looks different in the last 10 epochs for Model A than Model B. **Consider restricting your y-axis limits on both charts** somewhere between 0 and 0.2.

Choosing a number of epochs might be perplexing. I can recommend automizing it to you. **One of the common approaches is to stop training when your validation loss stops falling for a few epochs.** If you are using TensorFlow, embrace the [EarlyStopping](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping) mechanism.